# Second line of .sh script doesn't execute

Tags: bash, ubuntu

For some reason the `export` line doesn't execute when I run the following script. The line works fine when I run it manually. Any ideas? I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

```
#!/bin/bash

cgr drush/drush:~8.0
export DRUSH_LAUNCHER_FALLBACK=~/.composer/vendor/bin/drush
```

[Cgr](https://packagist.org/packages/consolidation/cgr) is an alternative to `composer global require`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not running the script with `.` or `source`, the export will run but not do anything, since the environment it's affecting is going away when it exits.

Comment: That did it -- thanks! I'll accept this once the timer expires.

Comment: Yep, another simple way to remember the limitation is that "*A child may never effect the environment of its parent.*"